# Who were the original (founding) members of The Expendables?

Tags: the-expendables

Throughout **[The Expendables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Expendables_(film_series))** franchise, we meet at least three of the original guys who founded the team/organization:

- Barney Ross (Sylvester Stallone)
- Conrad Stonebanks (Mel Gibson)
- Doc (Wesley Snipes)

Possibly also Trent Mauser (Arnold Schwarzenegger), as Barney commented Trent was on his old team... although it's never specified if he means the Expendables or something else. Perhaps also "Tool" (Mickey Rourke), who has retired from the life and now acts as a recruiting agent.

**Has anyone involved with the franchise said who the original founding members are?**